# Is there a Microsoft Edge equal of chrome --app to open a web app in msedge from command line

Tags: firefox, jupyter, progressive-web-apps, microsoft-edge

I want to open jupyter lab as a web app in Microsoft Edge. Like it is possible in chrome.
I've looked for configurations in firefox but they either don't support localhost or they are complex by making a new profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the website link of the app, you could use the code below via Command Prompt (cmd) to open it in Microsoft Edge:

```
start microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com
```

The result is like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Late into the question, but: Basically

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app="https://www.google.com"
```

... works. this can also be put into a shortcut and it shows up with an own icon in the Taskbar this way.

The exact same way it works if you first create a shortcut e.g. on your Desktop, starting with

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
```

changing it to the initial example from above via the shortcut properties... this will still miss the "correct" shortcut icon for the "app", anyway, it works.

BTW.: I also used Firefox for this, unfortunately they dropped support for --web-app cmd support in early 2021 ;/